# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'nativeVersion.major')

Tags: react-native

I got this error when I built and started a react-native app on expo.

The app was built using create-react-native-app and ran on an Android device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating to the latest version of expo app fixed this for me. Expo was probably expecting a previous version of react-native library and I was using the latest one.